# set default datetime format in python

Tags: python, mysql, django

How to set default datetime format in python because i have multiple tuples to send via template on client side. This is not good approach to set each object's value to specified format. I want to set a datetime format on server side and these converted values will be shown to client. I tried

```
datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
```

but it is giving error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your issue, but this might help
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
there is a datetime format section, this sets datetime format globally.

Answer (score 5):

`strftime` is a method of `datetime` objects - it doesn't set a default representation, which seems to be what you suggest.  For example, you might call it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
'2011-03-17 10:14:12'
```

If you need to do this a lot, it would be worth creating a method that wraps this conversion of a `datetime` to a string.  The documentation for the `datetime` module can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).